# show repeated selected text in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, selection

I don't know which text editor have it but when you select text it show up where the same text appear in text with a box. It's usefull when you select variable and it show up where it's use in the code.

The text can show up with different backgorund when I copy the text and then call the function and dissapear when position of the cursor change.

Is it possible to do this in Emacs (probably is but how)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Emacs has that (highlight matches of a given symbol or other pattern).  Sounds like any of these correspond to what you are looking for:

- Incremental search (aka isearch): `C-s` or `C-M-s`, then type what you want to match (or use `C-w`... to pick it up from the buffer).
- Library [`highlight-symbol`](http://nschum.de/src/emacs/highlight-symbol/).
- Library [`highlight`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/highlight.el), command `hlt-highlight-symbol`.  (And see option `` `hlt-auto-faces-flag ``.)  Does what library [`highlight-symbol`](http://nschum.de/src/emacs/highlight-symbol/) does, and more.
- Emacs 24.4 (i.e., current development snapshot), command `hi-lock-face-symbol-at-point`.

If you use library [`mouse3.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/mouse3.el) then right-clicking the mouse gives you the last two alternatives for the symbol under the mouse pointer.

Comment: `highlight-symbol` with `highlight-symbol-nav-mode` is perfect, thanks.

Comment: *FWIW:* Then so should `hlt-highlight-symbol` (in [`highlight.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/highlight.el)) be perfect.  You can similarly navigate among the occurrences of a given highlhghted symbol (I use keys `C-N` and `C-P`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try to use cedet with ECB on Emacs.
You can install it with  Meta+x list-packages or you can try another IDE like Kdevelop.